# SQL Server Triggers Update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have tables Student and Order. When I change the Student ID in the Student table I want the referencing rows in Order to be updated accordingly. I am using triggers. It is not working.

```
create TRIGGER Update_Student
ON dbo.Student
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @oldID int, @newID int
   Select @oldID = d.StudentID, @newID = i.StudentID
   from deleted d, inserted i
   Update Orders 
   set StudentID=@newID where StudentID=@oldID 
END
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: it is changing the id in the student table but not changing it in the order table

Answer (score 1):

You have several antipatterns in that. And your code cannot currently be fixed unless you have some other field to join inserted and deleted tables on.

First, never use implicit joins, that is a horrible coding technique. And what you did there gave you a cross join which is almost certainly not what you want. It is also one of the main reasons why implicit joins are a very poor technique.

Next you made the incorrect assumption that there would be only one record in inserted or deleted. This is not true and you should never design a trigger to handle only one record changes. If you updated 1000 students in one update statement, all 1000 records are in inserted and deleted. The way you wrote the code only one of them would be processed by the trigger. Anytime you are setting a scalar variable in a trigger to a value in inserted or deleted, you are going to have data issues at some point.

Next you have the problem that you are changing what is likely the Primary key in the student table which is almost always a bad idea. Primary keys should NEVER change. Do you have a natural key that is not changing? If not, how will you know which record relates to which one.

You might be able to get away with using name to join, but that is not usually a unique value. If your Student ID is not autogenerated, then the addition of an autogenerated id field would help you match the inserted and deleted tables together. If your current student id is autogenerated, then updating it is something that should be left only to people with extensive database experience who would know better than to do such a thing.

Comment: I know that I should not change a primary key and the logic seems incorrect to me as well. I have been asked to do such a code so I am looking for ways that could make it correct and logical....

Comment: The typical pattern to do such things is to create a new record in the parent table, then update the child records then delete the old record from the parent. This is almost never done in a trigger however but rather with a stored proc or a script (most commonly a script) as this is usually a one-time change.